# RegEx multiple optional characters in group

Tags: regex

How would I define optional characters in a group?

I am trying to match the following...

```
kg
kilo
kilos
kilogram
kilograms
g
gram
grams
```

I know I can put them individually in a group, but was wondering if I could do something fancy like this...

```
(kg|kilo?g?ram?s?)
```

Problem is it could match only the s? or none of the second alternation so it would match zero length.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oD8fA8/1

Comment: Your current regex actually matches such oddities as `kilorams` and `kilgras`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `(?:)` to group items without capturing (this works in most RegEx flavours; look up "non-capturing groups" in your engine's documetation if you are unsure).

With that, you can try something like this:

```
(k?g|(?:kilo)?grams?|kilos?)
```

This matches exactly

```
g kg gram grams kilogram kilograms kilo kilos
```

and nothing else.

Comment: It makes it possible to match `kilo` or `kilos`.

Answer (score 5):

I would start by enumerating all of the possible match conditions and then paring down from there to see if there is a more efficient solution:

```
kg|kilo|kilos|kilogram|kilograms|g|gram|grams
```

the plural 's' is an obvious redundancy:

```
kg|kilos?|kilograms?|g|grams?
```

g and kg can be collapsed:

```
k?g|kilos?|kilograms?|grams?
```

We can collapse the units for kilograms:

```
k?g|kilo(?:s|grams?)?|grams?
```

Are you OK with the six character duplication of "grams?" :)